# In a simple graph, why $\delta(G) \le \lfloor\dfrac{2e(g)}{n}\rfloor$ and $\Delta(G) \ge \lceil\dfrac{2e(G)}{n}\rceil$is true?

Tags: graph-theory

I can not see why this is always true.  I know that $2e(g)$ is the sum of the degrees.

Comment: I know that. $\dfrac{2e(G)}{n}$ is the average, then? That's all I can figure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, the sum of the degrees is $2e(g)$. This means the *average* degree is $2e(g)/n$. Now $\delta(G)$ is the *minimum* degree and $\Delta(G)$ is the *maximum* degree, and both of these must be integers. Can you see how your conclusion follows?

Comment: So this is simple as "The minimun is at most the average"?

Comment: You said it yourself :)

Comment: Thank you. I thought this had another things behind it.